# Content doesn't change on route change within same view

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Here is Vuejs3 Composition api route file. The SingleBoard.vue should display various content depending on the props passed:

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/singleboard/:dbName/:dbMethod/:securityType/:alertType",
        name: "singleboard",
        component: () => import("./SingleBoard.vue"),
        props: true
    }
];

export default routes;
```

And here is SingleBoard.vue:

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <h1>DB: {{ dbName }}</h1>
    <BoardContainer
        :dbName="dbName"
        :dbMethod="dbMethod"
        :securityType="securityType"
        :alertType="alertType"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from "vue";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
import BoardContainer from "@/modules/boards/BoardContainer.vue";


const route = useRoute();
let dbName = ref( route.params.dbName );
let dbMethod = ref( route.params.dbMethod );
let securityType = ref( route.params.securityType );
let alertType = ref( route.params.alertType );

// Function to update state based on new route parameters

// Watch for changes in route parameters and update state
watch( () => route.params, () => {
  console.log( "route.params.dbName: ", route.params.dbName );
  dbName = route.params.dbName;
  dbMethod = route.params.dbMethod;
  securityType = route.params.securityType;
  alertType = route.params.alertType;

} );
</script>
```

And here are sample of links:

```
<RouterLink
 to="/singleboard/StocksTopGainersFiltered/value/stock/list">Top gainers improved
 </RouterLink>

 <RouterLink
     to="/singleboard/StocksTopGainersStandard/value/stock/list">Top gainers standard
 </RouterLink>
```

When I go directly to a link, it loads fine. But when I click on another /singleboard/.... link to change content of view, content doesn't update. The props do get properly updated by the watch, but not the content.
I believe it's because some of the content of the included BoardContainer/ component do rely on onMonted method and that these life cycles method don't get triggered.

Is there anyway to trigger a life cycle reload upon change of route?

Comment: You can try use teleport https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/teleport.html#basic-usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simple as changing the main global router link to:

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

This forces the full cycle of page view to rerun on each page change.
The additional computation delay is negligible